# Only one way of string concatenation works with SMTPlib?

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
for each in foo:
    if each not in foo2:
        msg = ("""
        Some message:
        %s
        """
        % (each))
        server.sendmail(from, to, msg)
```

And it works fine and dandy. When I try to make it like this, however:

```
for each in foo:
    if each not in foo2:
        msg = "Some message:\n"+each
        server.sendmail(from, to, msg)
```

It sends blank email. It may be also worth noting that `each` is always a URL. Does it have something to do with how SMTPlib parses emails?

Comment: Aside from the trailing and leading newlines, those two blocks of code should do the same thing. Shouldn't you have `\r\n` at the end of it?

Comment: Starting whitespace may prevent it from incorrectly being interpreted as a header.... Try to view the source of the mail, or test what it does without the `:` in there.

Comment: Try replacing `msg` in your second code statement to `"\nSome message:\n"+each+"\n"`. Might be some problems with the header.

Comment: Are you using any authentication?  I had experiences with HTTP where the trailing newline on the base64 encoded credentials combined with the `\n\n` that signaled the end of headers in an odd way that made my 1st byte of data transmission a newline.  Not quite exactly the same, but maybe a similar issue somewhere?

Comment: .. not that it matters much here, but please always try to copy and paste exactly the code you're using (simplifying it to the smallest case beforehand, of course).  That can't be your code, because `from` is a keyword, and so can't be used as an identifier.